# LNK2019: Calling a function in WinMain

Tags: c++

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find the answer. Nobody has made anything like this apparently. I'm trying to get input from a user.

```
while(!done)
{
    PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL,PM_REMOVE);
    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
        done = true; //if found, quit app
    } else if (msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        game->KeyDown(msg.wParam);
    } else if (msg.message == WM_KEYUP) {
        game->KeyUp(msg.wParam);
    } else {
        /*  Translate and dispatch to event queue*/
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
return msg.wParam;
```

When I run it it gives me the error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Game::KeyDown(unsigned int &)" (?KeyDown@Game@@QAEXAAI@Z) referenced in function _WinMain@16
```

I have everything defined in the header of the game class... It's subsystem is set to nothing, but the "(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piece of cake.  "unresolved external symbol" most commonly means you declared a function without specifying what it does.  Consider the following example:

```
void undefined();
void LNK2019()
{
   undefined(); //the offending line
}
void main()
{
    //doesn't even have to do anything; it's not a runtime error
}
```

The function `LNK2019()` calls `undefined()`, but you never told `undefined()` what to do. Your linker doesn't know what to make of the line.  In your specific case, I'm betting `Game::KeyDown` doesn't have a body.

A few other comments on your code:

1. For Windows messages, avoid `if-else` trees; use `switch-case`.  It's commonly faster, and definitely more readable.
2. I've never seen messages handled in a loop like that.  Your [Windows Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381408%28VS.85%29.aspx) (whose function is commonly shortened to `WndProc`) should handle all Windows messages - the entire purpose of [`DispatchMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934(v=vs.85).aspx) is to send messages to that function.

Comment: After an hour of just looking for this error.. Thankyou.
I completely missed putting Game:: in front of KeyDown..

Comment: @BrandonWoolworth xD I know that feel bro. Consider accepting it as answer if it helped.